# Python: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in SelectMultipleField WTForm

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

When I go to the page `set.html` where the dropdown is, I get an error `builtins.TypeError TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

`form.responsible` сontains data of the following type:
`[(1534, 'None None (qa@app.com)'), (1535, 'Second Second (qa2@app.com)')]`

**view.py**

```
current_permission = Permissions.query.all()
users = []
for user in current_permission:
    receivers = user.group.users.all()
    for user in receivers:
        users.append(user)

if is_group_manager or assignee_from_unmanaged_group:
    form.responsible.choices = [
        (user.id, "{0} ({1})".format(user.details.full_name, user.email))for user in users
```

**set.html**

```
{% block page_block_content %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.responsible, class="form-control select2") }}
{% endblock %}
```

**form.py**

```
class AssignmentsForm(CSRFForm):
    responsible = SelectMultipleField(lazy_gettext("Select assignee"), choices=[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `SelectMultipleField` to `SelectField`

```
class AssignmentsForm(CSRFForm):
    responsible = SelectField(lazy_gettext("Select assignee"), choices=[])
```